# Download only changed tables in MySQL using checksum

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like to download a copy of a MySQL database (InnoDB) to use it locally. Since the database is growing rapidly, I want to find out a way to speed up this process and save bandwidth.

I'm using this command to copy the database to my local computer (Ubuntu):

```
ssh myserver 'mysqldump mydatabase --add-drop-database | gzip' | zcat | mysql mydatabase
```

I've added multiple `--ignore-tables` to ignore tables that don't need to be up to date.

I've already got an (outdated) version of the database, so there is no need to download all tables (some tables hardly change). I'm thinking of using the `checksum` for each table and add unchanged tables to `--ignore-tables`.

Since I can't find many example of using `checksums` and `mysqldump`, I'm brilliant (not very likely) or there is an even better way to download (or better: one-way sync) the database in a smart way.

Database replication is not what I'm looking for, since that requires a binary log. That's a bit overkill.

What's the best way to one-way sync a database, ignoring tables that haven't been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be using the mysqldump --tab option. [mysqldump delimited](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html)

```
mkdir /tmp/dbdump
chmod 777 /tmp/dbdump
mysqldump --user=xxx --password=xxx --skip-dump-date --tab=/tmp/dbdump database
```

Then use rsync with --checksum to send over changed files to destination. Run the create scripts, then load data using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)